# What is the difference between locator and selector?

Tags: xpath, selenium, phpunit

When I'm writing test scripts for PHPUnit, I read a lot about selectors and locators, but I don't really know what's the difference.

Does anyone know the difference?

Comment: i know squat about phpunit, but it may help to clarify: are you talking about using selenium with phpunit, and using the different types of locators (including xpath vs. css selectors) found here?: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html

Answer (score 1):

Selenium uses what is called locators to find and match the elements of your page that it needs to interact with. There are 8 locators strategies included in Selenium:

```
Identifier
Id
Name
Link
DOM
XPath
CSS
UI-element
```

Here the  CSS locator strategy uses CSS selectors to find the elements in the page.What else is your doubt in these?

Comment: So what's a selector then?

Comment: As I said in answer, when it comes to CSS, we start addressing the locators as CSS selectors. Css selectors are also locators.@mattboy